# Zend File Path Validation

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

In a zend framework application I want to validate a path to an image file. The file may be a previously uploaded file that reside in a folder inside the server machine or accessed via an url. I want to check weather the file path is valid or not. I don't want to use zend file element and upload the file. I have searched many times and was not successful. Could anyone tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for the PHP [file_exists](http://www.php.net/file_exists) function.

> Returns TRUE if the file or directory specified by filename exists; FALSE otherwise.

You could probably build a validator around that, or just use the function directly.

For files on remote servers you will probably need to use something like [file_get_contents](http://www.php.net/file_get_contents) which also returns false if the file doesn't exist.